# Compile & Run CLion Project from Terminal

Tags: makefile, terminal, cmake, clion

I am trying to create generally-accessible compile & run instructions for my CLion project, but can't find the exact terminal command it uses to execute the program (it's makefile, I would assume). From the project directory in the terminal, how would I do this?

The directory looks like this:

[image: file dir]

Answer (score 3):

I will add a little bit to @Stanley F.'s excellent answer.

FROM the root of the CLion project, this is what works for me.  I generally run with a debug profile.  The same can be reproduced for release.

When cmake  loads its project, it runs

```
cmake -Bcmake-debug-build -H. ${CMakeOptions}
```

where CMakeOptions is stored in CLion at

```
CLion->settings->Build,Execution, Deployment->CMake->[profile]->CMake Options
```

My general cmake build option is

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DSYTEM_ARCH=Linux-gcc5.3.0-x86_645 -CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14
```

[Note the lower-case d for 'debug'.  If I do not use this, my system will not work.  I wish that CLion did not default to 'Debug']

So, to reproduce what CLion creates upon project reload, I run

```
rm -rf cmake-debug-build  
cmake -Bcmake-debug-build -H. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DSYTEM_ARCH=Linux-gcc5.3.0-x86_645 -CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14
```

Then, to build the project, I run

```
cmake --build cmake-build-debug --target all
```

Please note that when I run the first cmake command (from CLion or the command line), cmake pulls in lots of libraries from other "precedent" projects as part of the processing of my CMakeLists.txt file.  If anything in one of those precedent projects changes, I will not pull them in anew, unless I physically delete the entire cmake-build-debug/ directory.  None of CLion's reset tool menu items from my experience will delete that file.

If I am running these commands from the CLion menus, then I have to physically delete the cmake-build-debug/ directory as well (if I have a change in one of the external libraries that I want to pull in).

Answer (score 1):

CLion currently only supports CMake projects. So you have to invoke the CMake executable with the appropriate parameters for your project.

At first, you can delete the `cmake-build-debug` folder, since this is auto-generated by CLion, which itself invokes CMake. It only contains temporary files.

So your build environment basically contains the `3DTable.c`, `3DTable.h` and `CMakeLists.txt` files. At least this is what I get from the screenshot.

To build the project from command line, first navigate to the source directory. Then invoke CMake:

```
cd <source path of Project_1>
cmake -Bbuild -H.
cmake --build build --target all
```

Notes:

- `build` is the directory, where CMake will generate temporary files and the build artifacts.
- The `-H.` option tells CMake, where the CMakeLists.txt file is located, which in this case is the current working directory.
- The library / executable for your project will be located within the `build` directory

Answer (score 0):

CLion can tell you, you don't need to hunt.

#### CMake command line

- Select **tools\cmake\reload cmake project**.
- The command line is shown in the **CMake** window.

#### Build command line

- Select **build\build project**.
- The command line is shown in the **messages** window.

#### Example

Mine look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.2.2/bin/ninja/win/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S C:\some_application -B C:\some_application\cmake-build-debug
...
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\some_application\cmake-build-debug --target all -j 9
```

#### Reminder

If using Visual Studio you still to specify which environment you are using. Typically this involves using the **VS command prompt** or executing one of the premade scripts to set up the environment variables. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#developer_command_file_locations).